# Jira Greenhopper Rapid Board client-side update event

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-agile

I created a javascript solution to show story points on the rapid board.
See comment in: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/GHS-6755.

I want to process the issues on the rapid board when it is dynamically loaded or updated. Is it possible to receive an event (javascript) when Greenhopper finishes updating the rapid board?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it:

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
    AJS.$(GH).bind('workModeUIReady', function() {
         // your code here
    });
});
```